# Maximum recursion depth exceeded with Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, recursion, sqlalchemy

I wrote this loop to dynamically build a select statement using Sqlalchemy in an attempt to have less DB hits.

I don't understand why I'm getting a Maximum recursion depth exceeded Error when `query.all()` is called.

When I change the recursion depth max to 2000 this query works fine.

Code:

```
filter_cond = False
for asset in assets:
    filter_cond = or_(filter_cond, and_(model.version == asset.get("version"),
                                        model.id == asset.get("id"),
                                        model.account_id == account_id))
query = session.query(model).filter(filter_cond)
result_set = query.all()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

currently you're building the following nested logic condition recursively in the for loop

```
or(...or(or(false, condition1), condition2), ... conditionN)
```

instead, if you express the equivalent condition:

```
or(condition1, condition2, ... conditionN)
```

using a list comprehension & unpacking, recursion is avoided.

```
def condition(model, asset):
    return and_(model.version == asset.get("version"),
                model.id == asset.get("id"),
                model.account_id == account_id)

filter_cond = or_(*[condition(model, asset) for asset in assets])
```

Comment: Would it be faster to avoid the list comp and unpacking altogether and just do a generator like so:              `filter_cond = or_((AuthorizationTool.build_statement(model, asset, account_id) for asset in assets))`

Comment: not sure that your generator expression would actually work, and re: speed, if performance is an issue, please test the block with various sized `assets`.

Comment: @RustyShackleford Generators optimize for memory usage, not speed, by generating elements as needed instead of up front. The cost is an extra call to the generator's `next` method for each element.

Comment: @Haleemur Ali It does work, I suppose or_ accepts any iteratable